# How can I use debounce to avoid triggering the graphQL query on every keystroke in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, graphql

I was given a new task and I have to debounce the input value to prevent a backend request on each keystroke and on the other hand CollectionsAutocomplete should have an internal useState with an input value, that is linked to the generalQuery variable.
Right now I was able to add the internal useState but I don't know how to apply the debounce.
The CollectionsAutocomplete is a component that is located in our library and I use it in a different project.
**Here is the CollectionsAutocomplete in the library:**

```
type CollectionsAutocompleteProps = GenericFetchAutocompletePropsWrapperType<StyleCollection>
  & {
    targetBrandNumber: string;
    queryVariables?: Exact<{
      brandNumber: string;
      generalQuery?: InputMaybe<string> | undefined;
      pagination: PaginationInput;
    }> | undefined;
    onInputChange?: (inputValue: string) => void;
  };

export const CollectionsAutocomplete = (props: CollectionsAutocompleteProps): ReactElement => {
  const { queryVariables, targetBrandNumber, value, handleOnBlur, handleOnChange, handleOnFocus, limitTags, onInputChange } = props;
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>('');

  return (
    <GenericFetchAutocomplete<
      StyleCollection,
      GetAllCollectionsQuery,
      GetAllCollectionsQueryVariables,
      true>
      limitTags={limitTags}
      value={value}
      dataMapper={(data): Array<StyleCollection> =>
        data.collections?.edges?.map((edge) => edge?.node).filter(sortUtil.isDefined) ?? []}
      fetchQuery={GetAllCollectionsDocument}
      inputLabels={{
        plural: 'Collections',
        single: 'Collection',
      }}
      queryOptions={{
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        context: { clientName: GraphClientNames['backend'] },
        variables: {
          generalQuery: queryVariables?.generalQuery ?? inputValue,
          brandNumber: targetBrandNumber,
          pagination: {
            first: 100,
            after: null,
          },
          ...queryVariables ?? {},
        },
      }}
      tagLabelFormatter={(option): string => `${option.collectionTerm} (${option.collectionName})`}
      textFieldProps={{
        ...props.textFieldProps,
        placeholder: value.length === 0 ? 'Select' : '',
        sx: {
          ['& ::placeholder']: {
            color: '',
          },
        },
      }}
      idKey='collectionNumber'
      optionLabelFormatter={(option): string => `${option.collectionTerm} (${option.collectionName})`}
      multiple
      onBlur={handleOnBlur}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      onFocus={handleOnFocus}
      onInputChange={(event): void => {
        const newValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        setInputValue(newValue);
        onInputChange?.(newValue);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

**here is how I use the CollectionsAutocomplete  in my project:**

```
<CollectionsAutocomplete
                  value={collectionsValue}
                  textFieldProps={{ required: true }}
                  targetBrandNumber={selectedBrands[0]?.brandNumber}
                  queryVariables={{
                    pagination: {
                      first: 200,
                      after: null,
                    },
                  }}
                  handleOnChange={(e, v): void => {
                    if (v !== null) {
                      setCollectionsValue(v);
                    } else {
                      setCollectionsValue([]);
                    }
                  }}
                  onInputChange={(newValue: string): void => {
                    console.log('Input value changed:', newValue);
                  }}
                />
```

I'm a bit lost about how to apply the logic.

Answer (score 0):

In an autocomplete scenario *throttling* the input is probably better than *debouncing* - you want to query the server regularly, but not on every keystroke.

There are many packages that supply a throttle function. For example [throttle-debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce)

```
npm install throttle-debounce --save
```

Then in your code:

```
import { throttle } from 'throttle-debounce';
…
handleOnChange={(e, v): void => throttle( 1000, setCollectionsValue(v ?? []))}
```

This will call `setCollectionsValue` at most every 1000 msec (once/sec).

Comment: my teacher told me to use the onInpuChange in the library. Do you suggest to apply your changes directly in the  handleOnChange() in the CollectionAutocomplete from my project and remove the changes in the library?

Comment: I'm not familiar with *CollectionsAutocomplete* but basically hook the throttle into whatever is receiving keyboard events. In normal js event terms you want to respond to `onChange` instead of `onBlur`

Comment: the solution was to apply a debounce() in the library component.